# docker - elasticsearch + kibana starting with saved objects

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I'm using docker-compose to start the elasticsearch and kibana together.

Everything is good, but I'm needing start with the saved objects too (with dashboards, visualize, index, etc).

Some one can help with that? How can I start with everything done (elasticsearch and kibana with the saved objects in the same time - dashboards, visualize, index, etc.)?

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.4.0
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,elasticsearch-cluster
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      # - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      # - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - api-network-driver

  elasticsearch-cluster:
    image: elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch-cluster
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,elasticsearch-cluster
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      # - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      # - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-cluster-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - api-network-driver

  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.4.0
    container_name: kibana
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - api-network-driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    version: '2.2' 
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.4.0
    container_name: kibana
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Kibana saves data (dashboards, visualizations, settings, etc.) into an index [.kibana], which is inside `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data.`
You've already mapped a volume for this folder, so your data will be stored on your host machine.
And also you can easily export all (dashboards, visualizations, settings, etc.) into a single .json format file and vise Versa.

[image]

I also recommend trying open distro from AWS, it´s open-source, include security features and docker-compose supported.

Comment: Thanks @Orest Gulman,

I mount the volume using this way - ./scripts/docker/elasticsearch/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data in my local. Is possible to start again, but my problem now is: the files is in my repository and everytime when I start the service again, my local files change. I try to use :ro (read-only) in the volume but the kibana not start.

Comment: You run elasticsearch in cluster?

Comment: Yes, you can see my docker-compose in the question.

Comment: I add a docker-compose example, that I've tested, and in my case, all data is still available after rebooting containers `docker-compose reboot` or `docker-compose down/up`. It 's deleting all data only in case if you specify `-v` option: `docker-compose down -v`.